# Bind XDocument to WPF and still use XPath?

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

This is a 2 part question.

1) Is it possible to bind XDocument to a WPF control without using ObjectDataProvider ?

Here is a snippet of my code in which XmlDocument works, but i cannot use XDocument

```
   XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
    provider.XPath = "/Parent/Child";
    provider.Document = mydoc; // xmldocument works fine.
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.XPath = "InnerChild/Name";
    binding.Source = provider;
    decisionCb.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

I need to retain the ability to bind using an XPath because my Xml document is generated on the fly. I wanted to use XDocument and LINQ :(

2) Is it possible to use XPath extension functions in XElement within Xaml ?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{}{http://myns}Child" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<!-- This wont work because Element cannot accept XPath -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Element[{http://myns}InnerChild/Name]}" /> 
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is "yes, you can".
One good article about this argument is the Beatrix Stollniz' one: [link text](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/index.php?s=xlinq)
About the second answer, I say "no, it is not possible". XLinq architecture is built taking advantage from the IEnumerable (basic Linq) extensions, so XPath would be unnecessary and (let's say) not-so-adequate.
Cheers

Comment: So,for example Is it possible to bind XDocument to a datagrid and still use XPath?

Comment: Article is gone.  :( That's why SO prefers you discuss the answer here rather than just link to it.