# Refactoring WPF Databinding: from XmlDocument+XPath to XElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xpath

I have a bunch of code that works off of databinding to XMLDocument using the XPath property.  I want to eliminate XMLDocument from my program and use XDocument and XElement and LINQ.  (The current program is a mess that uses both.)

Is there a way I can replace the databindings in my XAML by binding to an XElement, and not have to rewrite all the binding expressions?  I suppose the solution would use XPathSelectElement(s) but I'm not clear about how.

Ideally, I use code like

```
this.DataContext = xElement;
```

and keep or trivially change

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=path/to/child/@field}" />
```

IMPORTANT: this is not about TextBox.  I have much more complicated UserControls that build themselves with XPath bindings.

Research:
[Bind XDocument to WPF and still use XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665360/bind-xdocument-to-wpf-and-still-use-xpath) says it can't be done but I'm not convinced.  I'm imagining an extension method on XNode or something that implments XPath could work.

I haven't been able to find anything else on the topic.

If it can't be done in XAML, can you people suggest another approach that isn't too much rework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last week I have not found a satisfactory answer and am proceeding to rebuild dialogs.

I discovered that XmlDataProvider keys on SelectNodes() in XmlDocument to function, and ObjectDataProvider is intended to be used with XElement.

Possibly I can make an equivalent to SelectNodes as an extension method, and the key is to use it in the same fashion as Elements(), where you go

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=XElementSelectNodes[path/to/child].Value}" />
```

This is my working hypothesis, still working on it though.